# Loop over query in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to loop over a query result and combine the result.

I want to loop over the variable called rolling date, which gives out an array of dates with 30 day difference.

```
DECLARE rollingdate ARRAY<DATE>;
SET rollingdate = ( GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY), INTERVAL -30 DAY) );
```

My table is partitioned by DATE, and I'd like to loop over two consecutive dates from the rolling date and union all the results

```
select *, rollingdate[0]
from table
where date > rollingdate[1] and date < rollingdate[0]
union all

select *, rollingdate[1]
from table
where date > rollingdate[2] and date < rollingdate[1]
```

How do I achieve this in bigquery? i tried with bigquery scripts, but they don't take subqueries..

Comment: Are you just trying to add the rolling date? Not sure why you are dividing up your query only to union it again? Any given date will only fall into 1 time period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE dsql STRING DEFAULT '';
DECLARE rollingdate ARRAY<DATE>;
SET rollingdate = ( GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY), INTERVAL -30 DAY) );
WHILE i <= 2  
DO
  SET dsql = dsql || " select *, '" || rollingdate[ORDINAL(i)] || "' from table where date > '" || rollingdate[ORDINAL(i+1)] || "' and date < '" || rollingdate[ORDINAL(i)] || "' union all";
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
SET dsql = SUBSTR(dsql, 1, LENGTH(dsql) - LENGTH(' union all'));
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach like this should be ok:

```
with 
dates as (
 select * from unnest(generate_date_array(current_date, date_sub(current_date(), interval 365 DAY), interval -30 day)) as date
),
date_start_end as (
  select lag(date,1) over(order by date asc) as begin_date, date as end_date
  from dates
)
select table.*, end_date
from table
inner join date_start_end where date between begin_date and end_date
```

You might need to make adjustments depending if your date ranges are mean to be inclusive or exclusive.

As mentioned in my comment, any date in `table` will only be in 1 of your `rollingdate` intervals.  SQL is much more performant when you can do operations on a set and avoid loops.